# Cockatrice petrification circumstances?

Tags: nethack

If I'm riding my horse and I pound a cockatrice with my lance or attack it with ranged weaponry until it dies and I step on the same tile as the cockatrice corpse will it petrify me or my horse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't die from walking over a cockatrice corpse, although if you're blinded and feeling for what's on the ground without gloves you will touch the corpse and get petrified.

The only danger in not wearing boots around a c corpse is in kicking it.

I don't believe a pet can ever be petrified by a corpse that's not used to hit it.

Comment: Thanks much. How about if I'm mounted on my horse and engaged in melee combat with the cockatrice, can my horse become petrified from biting/attacking it?